# Custom HtmlHelper to render a Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, helper

I have created a custom `HtmlHelper` to render a `Grid`, and it's working fine, but I know for sure that it isn't written really nicely.

I'll provide you with the code that's most important for the grid.

First of all, the model which I pass to my grid is an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Then, the Razor syntax for the grid is as follows:

```
@(Html.GridFor()
    .Name("PageOverviewGrid")
    .WithColumns(model =>
    {
        model.Bind(x => x.Name);
        model.Bind(x => x.DateCreated);
        model.Bind(x => x.DateUpdated);
    })
)
```

Then I do have a custom HtmlHelper to render this grid:

```
 public static IGridBuilder<TModel> GridFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> htmlHelper)
 {
     return new GridBuilder<TModel>(htmlHelper);
 }
```

Then the `GridBuilder` class itself (it's constructed with interfaces so I can use a fluent API):

```
public class GridBuilder<TModel> : IGridBuilder<TModel>
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="GridBuilder{TModel}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">The <see cref="HtmlHelper{TModel}"/> that is used to render this one.</param>
    public GridBuilder(HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> htmlHelper)
    {
        this.htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
        this.properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public Dictionary<string, string> properties;

    #endregion

    #region IGridBuilder Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string name { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="HtmlHelper"/> that is used to build the grid.
    /// </summary>
    public HtmlHelper htmlHelper { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the name of the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name that the <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}"/> should have.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}"/> that is used to construct the grid.</returns>
    public IGridBuilder<TModel> Name(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Binds an column to the grid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TItem">The type of the column on which to bind the items.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="function">The functional that will bind the control to the grid.</param>
    public void Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> function)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(() => Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>(), typeof(TModel), name);

        properties.Add(metadata.PropertyName, metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the columns of the model that should be bound to grid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action that will bind all the columns.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IGridBuilder{TModel}"/> that is used to construct the grid.</returns>
    public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IGridBuilder<TModel>> action)
    {
        action.Invoke(this);
        return this;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IHtmlString Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an HTML-encoded string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns an HTML-encoded string.</returns>
    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        // Additional rendering is done here.
    }
}
```

And then now the things about which I'm concerned:

Retrieving the property display name or property name. (It's done through reflection right now, but I'm thinking that there is more friendly solution).

How can I render the data of the entity. For example, I want to have the `DateCreated` of a single entity in the grid.

```
foreach (var entity in htmlHelper.ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<GridPageFolderViewModel>)
{
    // For the entity get the properties and look in the directory of properties if it should be displayed. If that's the case, render it.
}
```

I have the feeling that this could be optimized, but it's my very first HTML extension. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please do not modify the original code after receiving answers.

Answer (score 6):

I like the fluent API. Nitpicks first:

- Drop the `#region` blocks. They only add clutter, for example `#region IHtmlString Members` is only confusing, since it's not immediately apparent that `GridBuilder` implements `IHtmlString` (perhaps `IGridBuilder` does? I'm not super familiar with these extensions myself, but I don't think it matters - comments shouldn't be misleading or confusing, period). Also `#region Properties` is a big fat lie; I'll get back to that.
- Vertical spacing isn't consistent. I prefer this:

  ```
  public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IGridBuilder<TModel>> action)
  {
      action.Invoke(this);
      return this;
  }
  ```

  Over that:

  ```
  public IGridBuilder<TModel> Name(string name)
  {
      this.name = name;

      return this;
  }
  ```

---

Now the more important stuff.

> ```
> #region Properties
>
> public Dictionary<string, string> properties;
>
> #endregion
> ```

This isn't a *property*, the comment describing the region is very, very misleading. **This is a publicly exposed field** - client code is completely free to reassign the `Dictionary<string, string>` reference to whatever it wants. Exposing public fields breaks encapsulations. **Expose properties, not fields.**

Your naming conventions are confusing, inconsistent and error-prone. All `public` members should be `PascalCase` - keep `camelCase` for local variables and private fields; I'd also recommend prefixing private fields with an `_` underscore (still `_camelCase` for private fields) so that you can get rid of the `this` qualifier, and only use it when it's actually needed - i.e. when you're *returning* `this`, or passing `this` as a parameter to a method/delegate.

```
public string name { get; private set; }
public IGridBuilder<TModel> Name(string name)
```

Would be:

```
private string _name;
public string Name { get { return _name; } }
public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithName(string name);
```

Notice how none of these names are ambiguous in any way.

---

The parameter naming could be more meaningful here:

```
public void Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> function)
public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IGridBuilder<TModel>> action)
```

These parameters are closer to being *methods*, and naming them as such (still `camelCase` though) would be more helpful and wouldn't *require* relying on the XML documentation / IntelliSense to know what that function/action is supposed to be doing:

```
public void Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> propertySelector)
public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IGridBuilder<TModel>> bindAllColumns)
```

I'm recommending such naming, because this:

```
action.Invoke(this);
```

Could then also be written like this:

```
bindAllColumns(this);
```

..which is much more meaningful.

---

Lastly, this line *may* have a minor bug:

```
properties.Add(metadata.PropertyName, metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName);
```

`DisplayName` being a `string`, the null-coalescing operator isn't ideal. I'd split it in two instructions:

```
var displayName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.DisplayName)
                            ? metadata.PropertyName
                            : metadata.DisplayName;
properties.Add(metadata.PropertyName, displayName);
```

Comment: First of all. Thank you very much for the valuable feedback. I'll change my code. But I was also looking for other solutions to get rid of the reflection and the dictionary. Maybe there are other ways to accomplish what I've done because I have the feeling it overkill. Any idea on that?